# time() results a different time

Tags: php, datetime

I think it has something to do with PHP Timezones. My current date and time is 10:51 pm , and 7/15/2013 . (I am on windows and my bottom right is showing it :) )

I use the following php code

```
<?php
echo date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
?>
```

And the browser displayed: `15/07/13 : 19:06:15` 
(about 3 hours and 45 minutes early).

First Question: Why does it happen?

Second Question: If it is because PHP's default timezone is something else (mine is GMT 5:45), how can i edit the php's conf (or whatever) so that time() returns time for my timezone?

Comment: Is your server running locally?

Comment: yap! its running  locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set the time zone in your php.ini file or you can do it in the code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Also `date_default_timezone_get()` will show you what timezone you currently have set.

Comment: can you tell me a place where i can find 'America/Los_Angeles' type of list for all timezones?

Answer (score 2):

You should look [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) at your `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that PHP is *server*-side. The time it returns is bound to the server the code is running on. The php.ini setting is `date.timezone`. But you can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to override the timezone specifically for your script. If you want to get the time in the timezone of the *client*, however, you have to use a *client*-side method like Javascript.

Comment: thanks. i knew that php is server side and it is returnig time of server (and i had tested it locally) . Thanks again anywas